# How can I have my button link to another js file using React?

Tags: reactjs

FYI, I am new to React. How can I have my button on my home page of my restaurant website link my menu.js file? I'm assuming this is fairly simple, but I couldn't find the syntax to link my menu page to my home page.

Here is my code so far.

```
         <div>
            <Card className="text-center">
                <Card.Header>Featured</Card.Header>
                <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Title>Menu</Card.Title>
                    <Card.Text>
                    orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. At consectetur lorem donec massa sapien. Euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate odio ut.
                    </Card.Text>
                    <Button onClick={clickMe}>
                        View Full Menu
                    </Button>
                </Card.Body>
                <Card.Footer className="text-muted"></Card.Footer>
            </Card>
        </div>
```

Comment: There are multiple ways to achieve it. If you are okay with including menu.js component within the `Card`, you may use a switch/toggle (state) variable (say `showMenu`) and render something like: `{showMenu && <Menu..../>}` either within the `Card` or within the outer-div. So, `clickMe()` will need to set `showMenu` to `true` or `false` (ie, flip-it).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Link component and define the menu component in the Route component.

```
import { Link,Route } from 'react-router-dom';

<Link to='/menu'>
    View Full Menu
</Link>
<Route path="/menu">
   <Menu />
</Route>
```

Read more: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link